# How to get DotCover coverage in TeamCity from Cake

Tags: teamcity, dotcover, cakebuild

I've recently adopted the build tool [Cake](https://cakebuild.net/), but I'm struggling to get DotCover unit test coverage reports to show in TeamCity.

I've tried the following task:

```
Task("Run-Regression-Tests")
    .IsDependentOn("Build")
    .Does(() =>
{
    var resultPath = artifactsDirectory + File("results.dcvr");
    DotCoverCover(tool => 
        {
            tool.NUnit3(new[] {
                "./Foo.UnitTests/bin/" + configuration + "/Foo.UnitTests.dll",
                "./Bar.UnitTests/bin/" + configuration + "/Bar.UnitTests.dll",
                "./Baz.IntegrationTests/bin/" + configuration + "/Baz.IntegrationTests.dll"
            }, new NUnit3Settings {
                NoResults = true
            });
        },
        resultPath,
        new DotCoverCoverSettings()
            .WithFilter("+:Foo.Domain"));

    TeamCity.ImportDotCoverCoverage(resultPath);
});
```

However this produces the following output from TeamCity:

```
// Output immediately after unit test success report:

[03:01:52][Step 1/1] [JetBrains dotCover] Coverage session finished [30/09/2017 03:01:52]
[03:01:52][Step 1/1] [JetBrains dotCover] Coverage results post-processing started [30/09/2017 03:01:52]
[03:01:53][Step 1/1] [JetBrains dotCover] Coverage results post-processing finished [30/09/2017 03:01:53]
[03:01:53][Step 1/1] 
[03:01:53][Step 1/1] ========================================
[03:01:53][Step 1/1] Create Octopus Release
[03:01:53][Step 1/1] ========================================
[03:01:53][Step 1/1] Importing data from 'artifacts/results.dcvr' (7.49 MB) with 'dotNetCoverage' processor

// After cake finishes:

[03:02:11]Waiting for 1 service processes to complete
[03:02:11]Processing 1 coverage report(s)
[03:02:11]Generating coverage report by dotcover for files: [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\47e2e68a6c48ce48\artifacts\results.dcvr]
[03:02:11]Get dotCover version (1s)
[03:02:13]Use DotCover 2016 and higher commands set
[03:02:13]Merge dotCover reports
[03:02:14][Merge dotCover reports] Started dotCover: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\tools\dotCover\dotCover.exe merge C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\dotcover4470082908956100659.xml
[03:02:14]
[Merge dotCover reports] Output: JetBrains dotCover Console Runner 2017.1.1. Build 108.0.20170407.130252
Copyright (c) 2009-2017 JetBrains s.r.o. All rights reserved.
[JetBrains dotCover] Snapshot merging started [30/09/2017 03:02:13]
[JetBrains dotCover] Source snapshots number: 1
[03:02:14][Merge dotCover reports] [JetBrains dotCover] Failed to merge snapshots. Set of standalone sections doesn't comply ReverseFunctionCoverageSnapshotDataDescriptor specification. Set of standalone sections doesn't comply ReverseFunctionCoverageSnapshotDataDescriptor specification
[03:02:14]
[Merge dotCover reports] 
[03:02:14][Merge dotCover reports] dotCover exited with code: -2
[03:02:14][Merge dotCover reports] dotCover returned non-zero exit code.
[03:02:14]Remove dotCover snapshot files
[03:02:14]Generate dotCover report
[03:02:15][Generate dotCover report] Started dotCover: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\tools\dotCover\dotCover.exe report C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\dotcover1750892168641886115.xml
[03:02:15]
[Generate dotCover report] Output: JetBrains dotCover Console Runner 2017.1.1. Build 108.0.20170407.130252
Copyright (c) 2009-2017 JetBrains s.r.o. All rights reserved.
[03:02:15][Generate dotCover report] [JetBrains dotCover] Report source "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\dotCover1103887209553630063Merge" doesn't exist. 
[03:02:15]
[Generate dotCover report] 
[03:02:15][Generate dotCover report] dotCover exited with code: -2
[03:02:15][Generate dotCover report] dotCover returned non-zero exit code.
[03:02:15]Generate dotCover HTML report
[03:02:15]Packing snapshot files
[03:02:15][Packing snapshot files] Started dotCover: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\tools\dotCover\dotCover.exe zip C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\dotcover5049141835197969589.xml
[03:02:15]
[Packing snapshot files] Output: JetBrains dotCover Console Runner 2017.1.1. Build 108.0.20170407.130252
Copyright (c) 2009-2017 JetBrains s.r.o. All rights reserved.
[03:02:15][Packing snapshot files] [JetBrains dotCover] Source file doesn't exist.
```

It seems that TeamCity is trying to merge dotcover snapshots but I don't think I'm telling it to. I also find it strange that the artifacts/results.dcvr are being uploaded after the deploy to octopus task has started

I've tried using DotCoverAnalyze with a resultPath of "result.xml" but TeamCity reports that it is an invalid file format.

So, how do you collect and import DotCover coverage with cake and TeamCity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I currently import dotCover coverage report to TeamCity. Notice how I give the absolute path to DotCover.exe home directory in order to override bundled DotCover.exe. This might be useful when there might be incompatibility between the bundled DotCover version and the one you are using with Cake (e.g. the one found in your `.\tools` folder.

```
Task("Run-Unit-Tests")
    .IsDependentOn("Build")
    .Does(() =>
{
    DotCoverCover((ICakeContext c) => {
            c.NUnit3("./src/**/bin/x64/" + parameters.Configuration + "/Foo.Test.dll",
                new NUnit3Settings
                {
                    Results = parameters.Paths.TestResult,
                    TeamCity = parameters.IsTeamCity
                }
            );
        },
        parameters.Paths.CoverageResult,
        new DotCoverCoverSettings()
            .WithFilter("+:Foo")
            .WithFilter("-:Foo.Test"));
})
.Finally(() =>
{
    if(parameters.IsTeamCity)
    {
        TeamCity.ImportData("nunit", parameters.Paths.TestResult);
        TeamCity.ImportDotCoverCoverage(
            parameters.Paths.CoverageResult,
            MakeAbsolute(Directory("./tools/JetBrains.dotCover.CommandLineTools/tools")));
    }
    else
    {
        DotCoverReport(
            parameters.Paths.CoverageResult,
            parameters.Paths.CoverageResult.ChangeExtension("html"),
            new DotCoverReportSettings
            {
                ReportType = DotCoverReportType.HTML
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: You could enhance to above code by using Cake's built in tool locator to get the path of dotcover.exe. Then the code would look something like `MakeAbsolute(Context.Tools.Resolve("dotcover.exe").GetDirectory())`